# FB Prophet ".fit()" gives weird output message

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am training a FB Prophet model and I am wondering about the output.
Here is my code:

[image]

```
 model_multivariate = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.5, seasonality_prior_scale = 0.01, holidays = holi) 
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("wk-1_nvf_fcst",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("wk-2_nvf_fcst",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("wk-3_nvf_fcst",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("wk-1_vr_fcst",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("wk-2_vr_fcst",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("wk-3_vr_fcst",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("year",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("ib_units_trend",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("autocorr_ib_units_lag8",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("autocorr_ib_units_lag7",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("autocorr_ib_units_lag2",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("month_cos",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("week_of_year_cos",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("day_of_year_cos",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.add_regressor("autocorr_order_count_lag7",standardize=False)
 model_multivariate.fit(train)
```

When executing this cell I get the following:
[image]

For me this looks weird, because before adding some of these additional regressors I dind't get these messages with: "Out[300]: <prophet.forecaster.Prophet at 0x2...>"

So does anyone know what this means?

Also I am wondering what the error message: "16:03:40 - cmdstanpy - ERROR - Chain [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGEbg.png) error: error during processing Unknown error
Optimization terminated abnormally. Falling back to Newton" means.

The model prediction and everything else works, I just want to get sure that every additional regressor gets used by the model, as these messages were not here before.

Thanks!